# What is the full list of ChainSpec properties?

Tags: genesis, chainspec

The `ChainSpec` type has a `from_genesis` method which takes an `Option<Properties>`. This `Properties` object is:

```rust
/// Arbitrary properties defined in chain spec as a JSON object
pub type Properties = serde_json::map::Map<String, serde_json::Value>;
```

I can't find any documentation on the full list of the available keys for the ChainSpec properties and what they mean / do. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Properties` field in the Chain Specification is intentionally arbitrary. As you see in the comment:

> Arbitrary properties defined in chain spec as a JSON object

As a chain spec creator, you can add whatever you want in here, and it can be used by clients or libraries which are programmed to interpret that data.

At the time of writing this post, the "common" properties included with a chain spec are:

```js
// from Kusama
"properties": {
    "ss58Format": 2,
    "tokenDecimals": 12,
    "tokenSymbol": "KSM"
}
```

These are used by Polkadot JS and other front-end libraries to improve the user experience, but are not strictly required.

Comment: In chains where there are multiple balance instances, the `tokenDecimals` and `tokenSymbol` can be arrays of values as well.

Answer (score -3):

The chain spec docs link
https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_chain_spec/struct.GenericChainSpec.html#method.from_genesis

And do you know that you can produce a json file which is the chain_spec and check the keys using ... -build-spec command flag